# Combination Optimization for Increasing Precision

Tags: algorithm, combinations, precision

I'm looking for a suggestion/ approach to the following problem:

I have a list of phrases that have been tagged by hand as either an adjective phrase
or a verb phrase. My program will identify what category each phrase fits into based on
9 different parameters. Each parameter is given a weight from 0 to 3 in increments of .25 
(0, .25, .5, .75, 1, 1.25, 1.5,...). For a small subset of phrases I would like to find 
the optimal values each parameter should be set to in order to achieve the highest 
precision for that set. This will give me a better understanding of what parameters 
are more important and should have a higher weight when run on the final list
of phrases.

Performing a brute force search is not a realistic option. Testing all the combinations
for nine different parameters means the program will run in O(n^9). Ain't nobody got
time for that. I have also considered using random combinations and hope that a good
combination is found quickly, but I would prefer a more systematic approach.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, or an algorithm to look into that would be 
greatly appriciated.

Comment: Multiple linear regression will solve this problem, though in general it won't find weights that are multiples of 0.25.

Comment: Is this just a polynomial classification algorithm? parameter 1 times weight 1 + parameter 2 * weight 2 ... = classification.

Comment: The parameters are broken up into two categories. If parameters 1 - 5 have a higher combined weight than parameters 6 - 9 the phrase will be labeled as adj phrase while if parameters 6 - 9 have a higher combined weight than parameters 1 - 5 the phrase will be labeled as a verb phrase. For example If the parameters have the following weights: p1: 1 p2: 0 p3: 1.5 p4: 0 p5: 1 p6 :2 p7: .25 p8: .25 p9: 0. The score for adjective phrase would be 3.5 (1 + 1.5 + 1 using parameters 1-5) and the score for verb phrase would be 2.5 (2 + .25 + .25 using parameters 6-9). Thus, the phrase is labeled as adj.